# packages and classes not found by eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on creating an android app, and I've found that many classes and packages apparently "don't exist", such as `javax.security.sasl.SaslClient`. Why is Eclipse not finding these packages & classes?

It seems as thought many of the security and auth classes are missing.

Comment: you add .jar file proper ? and in reference check this package and class r there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findjar.com` to get the required jars, include them in your project and build path. It is probably that the classes that you are looking for are not part of the standard JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Download `javax.security.sasl.SaslClient` the jar file from [here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.security.sasl.SaslException) and put it in your android project's build path.